# how to read words in the url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i always read the first word for example the word " something" after the port number using jquery/javascript?

Here is the url and i want to get whatever the first word after the port number

http://www.aaa.com:1081/something/arap/con.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentUrl= window.location.pathname;
    alert (currentUrl);
});
```

Comment: Given this string: `"/something/arap/con.html"` how would you get `"something"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
```

But you probably want to use something like this instead: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
   //Then access the different parts by the parts of the array, like
    var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentUrl= window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
    alert (currentUrl);
});
```